# .htaccess mode rewrite engine seems not working in my local marchine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls like this `http://localhost/mysite/index.php?page=something` which I only want to be `http://localhost/mysite/something` and on the homepage it should be `http://localhost/mysite/` not `http://localhost/mysite/index.php` by using .htaccess

Below is my code in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    rewriterule ^([^-]+)$ index.php?page=$1[L]
</IfModule>
```

But it shows the same to what has been before. I don't know if I wrote something wrong to the code above or maybe my apache does not support it because I never knew it before.

Could someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation on [rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and provide the output here so we may better assist you.

Comment: It seems not working with my condition <Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c> coz if I delete this condition, it shows the 500 internal error

Answer (score 0):

If `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is failing, then you don't have the rewrite module compiled in apache, or it isn't loaded. Do you have this somewhere in your config?

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(or if there is a conditional `<IfDefine>` around it, make sure the define is satisfied)