# .htaccess rewrite url to make SEO friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have posted somewhat related to this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484853/htaccess-mode-rewrite-engine-seems-not-working-in-my-local-marchine), but I seem not get the right answer. So could anyone help me to change the address like this:

```
example.com/index.php?page=something => example.com/something

and example.com/index.php => example.com
```

in the .htaccess file?

Here is my website link www.panhareach.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm using it now. But I'm afraid it requires more configurations, isn't it? coz I don't see any changes to my url. Please check it at `www.panhareach.com`. Thanks V.Melnychuk

Comment: You should change the links in your web-site, links like http://www.panhareach.com/buy-on-rent/ seems to be working

Comment: that's a great help. Thanks so much