# JS Error while work on .htaccess rewrite url to make SEO friendly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I use this code for make my site's dynamic URL seo friendly. ([.htaccess rewrite url to make SEO friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589519/htaccess-rewrite-url-to-make-seo-friendly))
The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and its only display Index page.

My Normal working URL is `http://www.gayatrigeo.com/productdesc.php?id=1` but if you visit `http://www.gayatrigeo.com/productdesc/1` then you can see the issue.

Here is my .htaccess file code

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Any Help 'll appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Done, I made mistake in .htaccess. need to write "productdesc.php" and wrote "index.php".

Comment: JavaScript is not a black box. You can actually see the source code and possibly spot what's wrong.